# Establishing and locating zeros of a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

In search for the purely imaginary roots of the polynomial $p(z) = z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 3z + 7$, I first replaced $z$ by $iy$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ which yields
$$p(iy) = y^4 - i y^3 - 4 y^2 + 3 iy + 7$$
which by separating into Real and Imaginary parts yields
$$p(iy) =( y^4 - 4 y^2  + 7 ) + iy (3-y^2) .$$

To find the common zeros let $\text{Re} f(z)=0$ and $\text{Im} f(z) =0$ which yields respectively,
$$y=2 \pm i\sqrt{3} ~~ \text{and} ~~ y =0, \pm \sqrt{3} .$$

The first pair of values turned out to be themselves complex numbers. So I guess there are no purely imaginary roots as $y$ supposed to be a real number.

Next, I want to find the change of the argument of $\text{arg} (f(z))$ when $z$ traverses on the imaginary axis from $z = R$ (sufficiently large) to $z=0$. How can I go about and solving this problem ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: arg (z) is just the angle $\alpha$ such that $tan{\alpha} =\frac{Im(z)}{Re(z)}$. So you have formula for $\alpha$ in terms of $arctang$ function. Now, as you showed, real part grows "faster" then imaginary (polynomial of degree 4 vs 3). Analyze this ratio and use your knowledge of $arctang$ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the polynomial  $ \ z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 3z + 7 \ $ has real coefficients, any purely imaginary zeroes occur in complex-conjugate pairs.  If there were such a pair $ \ \pm \ i·\alpha \ \ , \ $ the other two zeroes must either be a pair of distinct real zeroes  $ \ r \ , \ s \ \ ; \ $ a "double" real zero $ \ r \ \ ; \ $ or a pair of complex-conjugate zeroes $ \ \beta \ \pm \ i·\gamma \ \ . $  (We have $ \ \alpha \ , \ \beta \ , \ \gamma \ $ also real.)

The Viete relations permit us to follow the implications of this.  The sum of the zeroes is $ \ -1 \ \ , \ $ so we must have either $ \ r + s \ , \ 2·r \ , \ $ or $ \ 2·\beta \ $ equal to $ \ -1 \ \   $ (the last case shows, incidentally, that there *cannot* be a second purely imaginary pair).  The linear coefficient is the negative of the sum of all products of three of the zeroes, so either $ \ (r + s)·\alpha^2 \ , \ 2·r·\alpha^2 \ , \ $ or $ \ 2·\beta·\alpha^2 \ $ is equal to $ \ -3 \ \ . \  $  Therefore, we *must* have $ \ \alpha^2 \ = \ 3 \ \ . $

Next, the quadratic coefficient is the sum of all pairwise products of the zeroes, which requires that $ \ rs + \alpha^2 \ , \ r^2 + \alpha^2 \ , \ $ or $ \ (\beta^2 + \gamma^2) + \alpha^2 \ $ be equal to $ \ 4 \ \ . \ $  Thus, the product of the two zeroes which are not purely imaginary is $ \ +1 \ \ . \ $  (So for this polynomial, we have not found any "sticking points" concerning the *signs* of the coefficients.)  But these results lead us to the conclusion that the product of all four zeroes is $ \ 3·1 \ \neq \ 7 \ \ . \ $  Our premise is *false*: this polynomial **does not** have purely imaginary zeroes.

In passing, we have also shown that a monic quartic polynomial that has a pair of purely imaginary zeroes must have the form $$   z^4 \ + \ b·z^3 \ + \ c·z^2 \ + \ \alpha^2·b·z \ + \ \alpha^2·(c - \alpha^2) \ \ . \ $$

[So the zeroes of $ \ z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 3z + \mathbf{3} \ $ *do* include a purely imaginary pair.]  If *both* pairs of complex zeroes are purely imaginary, the polynomial will simply have the "biquadratic" form $ \ z^4  \ + \ (\alpha^2 + \gamma^2)·z^2 \ + \ \alpha^2 · \gamma^2 \ \ . $

Answer (score 2):

$y$ must be a real number.

Since there is no real number satisfying $y^4-4y^2+7=0$ and $y(3-y^2)=0$ at the same time, there is no purely imaginary root of $z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2+3z+7 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you ! That I figured. Next task is to find the change in the argument of $f(z)$ when $z$ traverses on the imaginary axis from a sufficiently large $R$ to the origin which I can't figure out.

Comment: Could you clarify your ultimate goal? I'm not sure why it is important for you to analyze $\arg z$ on the imaginary axis. By the way, you can easily see the behavior by noticing $\tan \theta = \frac{y(3-y)^2}{y^4-4y^2+7}$ , where $\theta = \arg z$ and differentiate the right-hand side.

Comment: @I H, I am trying to locate the zeros of $p$. eliminating the possibilities of real and imaginary zeros. I know the expression for $\tan (\cdot)$. The issue here since $y$ is not real, so it's path cannot be considered.

Comment: No, $y$ is real.

Comment: @I H, I meant according to the calculation.

Comment: That's your calculation for identifying the roots of $p(iy)=0$. Now we are turning to calculate $\arg p(it), y \in \mathbb{R}$ and the roots of $p(iy)=0$ is irrelevant.